# How to place a line which exists in one perl file , to another txt file after particular string matches

Tags: perl, append, pattern-matching

I am writing one perl script which is having some if else conditions. There is another .txt file in which, I want to place that conditional statements which exists in if else (in perl file) after a certain string. i did some search for this but most of the programs are based on merging two files. But in my case one file is perl file itself in which conditional statements exist and other is text file in which I want to append that conditional statements after a certain string. My files look like-

```
File 1
If (n==1 && m==1){ 
print (".include xyz.txt")}
else if(n==1 && m==0){
print (".include abc.txt")}.....

File 2 
lines....
lines....
*matching string
Here I want to append #.include xyz.txt
lines....
lines....
```

Can both files run simultaneously and my conditional statements can be added in another file? Or first I have to take output from file 1 in other output file then to append it in second file. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -MFcntl=:seek -pe 'seek(ARGV,0,SEEK_END) if /match/ and !$c++' fil1 fil2
```

It skips to `fil2` file when it finds string `match` within `fil1`, and `!$c++` ensures that skipping occurs only once.

Comment: do i need to write this line on command line? What in case of multiple  replacements?

Comment: @Suhan please add to your question how these multiple replacements should behave.

Comment: In case of multiple replacements my file would be look like-                          File1 If(n==1 && m==1){

Comment: In case of multiple replacements my file would be look like-                           File 1
If (n==1 && m==1){ 
print (".include xyz.txt")}
else if(n==1 && m==0){
print (".include abc.txt")}.....
If(x==1){
print(".include test1.txt")}
else if(x==2){
print(".include test2.txt")}

File 2 
lines....
lines....
*matching string 1
Here I want to append #.include xyz.txt
*matching string 2
Here I want to append #.include test1.txt
lines....
lines....